# Angular Expression in ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to create a custom select element with an Angular directive.

The template in this directive contains a select element with a ng-model attribute that I want to get from the custom element.

```
<custom-select inner-model="modelName">
    <select model="{{model}}"></select>
</custom-select>
```

My problem is Angular doesn't allow an Angular expression as a value for the ng-model attribute.

I also tried to set an attribute with

```
link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
    element[0].childNodes[0].setAttribute('data-ng-model', attributes.innerModel);
}
```

It does take the attribute with the right value but it is still not working.

Here's my plunker : [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/b3pZNI?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define an isolated scope. This will essentially bind the outer scope property assigned to `inner-model` attribute to internal scope property `innerModel`, which you could then use in your template.

```
app.directive('customSelect', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
       innerModel: "="
    }
    template: '<select ng-model="innerModel" data-ng-transclude></select>',
  };
});
```

Then you could do:

```
<custom-select inner-model="someScopeProperty">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  ...
</custom-select>
```

(Although, I'm still puzzled by what you are trying to achieve)

Comment: Thank you! It worked great! What I'm trying to achieve is to create a custom select with an element under this select (with opacity 0). But I needed this select to work properly with the model first.

Comment: You should ask a new question and provide more data

Comment: I thought it was unnecessary since more data is just css. Or should I update the plunker?

Comment: I guess I just don't fully understand what you want to do. You could edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I edited a bit the plunker. I didn't go to far with the css but it shows what I wanted. Thank you for your answers anyway.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what you want or the issue you face. what css are you referring to?